# Generates random numbers with python and display on grafana

Tags: python-3.x, grafana, influxdb, alpine-linux, telegraf

I would like in alpine linux to create a program in python that generates random numbers. I have succeeded in this part. But now I would like the generated number to be saved in Telegraf so that I can display it in my dashboard with grafana. So how can I do that?

Comment: Please add the code you have written AND what you have tried. Without that, it is hard to give specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

This  may be what you want

```
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec
```

This plugin can be used to poll for custom metrics from any source.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it right away, if it works a big thank you because I've been looking for 2 weeks